# Vue.set updates copied objects in vuex store

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, state-management

When I select an object for editing, the vuex store creates a working copy of the object to make a reset to the initial object state possible.

The initial loading mutation looks like this (when i select an object in a tablegrid):

```
@Mutation
  private [MutationTypes.LOAD_OBJECT_DETAILS_SUCCESS](object: ObjectDetailViewModel) {
Vue.set(this.State.detail, 'initalObject', object);
Vue.set(this.State.detail, 'workingCopyofObject', cloneDeep(object));
}
```

I am using the loadash CloneDeep Method, but I get the same failure when I am using plain js object copy like:  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(router)))`.

Now when I try to update the working copy of the object, the Vue.Set Method also updates my initial object.

```
  @Mutation
  private [MutationTypes.UPDATE_WORKINGCOPY_Object](updateProp: KeyValuePair) {

      Vue.set(this.State.detail.workingCopyofObject, updateProp.key, updateProp.value);

  }
```

So when I call my reset mutation, i won't get my initial values:

```
 @Mutation
 private [RouterMutationTypes.DISCARD_WORKINGCOPY_CHANGES]() {
   Vue.set(this.State.detail, 'workingCopyofObject', this.State.detail.initalObject); // initialObject already contains the changes of the working copy
 }
```

Maybe I just missed something about how the Vue.set Method is supposed to work.

Best Regards,

Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your reset mutation.  You're setting the working copy to be the initial object, which defeats the purpose of the copy.  With anything like the following program flow, you will see the duplicating behavior you saw:

> Set > Update > Reset -- At this point any future Update will affect both objects

An easy fix would be to clone the initial object on reset:

```js
@Mutation
private [RouterMutationTypes.DISCARD_WORKINGCOPY_CHANGES]() {
   const clone = cloneDeep(this.State.detail.initalObject);
   Vue.set(this.State.detail, 'workingCopyofObject', clone);
}
```